# How to sync data from 2 different columns to another speadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet where I am trying to sync 2 sheets with column 13 and 14 by comparing it to Column column 2 Serial Numbers

I was able to get this code working to sync only one of the column which is Column 13 but now I want to also sync column 14 to the same sheet. Can anyone help me out here on what changes I have to do to replicate it with multiple columns?

```
    function updateMaster(sn,valuen) 
    {
      var destfile=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID");
      var ds=destfile.getSheetByName("SheetName");
      var lr=ds.getLastRow();
      var values=ds.getRange(1, 2,lr,1).getValues();
      for (var i=1;i<lr;i++)
      {
       // Browser.msgBox(values[i][0] + " " + sn)

        if(values[i][0]==sn)
        {
          ds.getRange(i+1, 33).setValue(valuen);
                break;   
        }
      }    
    }   

    function ReadRow(e) 
    {
      var range = e.range;
      sht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var col=range.getColumn();
      var row=range.getRow();
      var value=range.getValue();
      if(col==13)
      {
        var sn=sht.getRange(row,2).getValue();

    //   Browser.msgBox(sn)
        updateMaster(sn,value) 
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync both column 13 and 14 instead of column 13 only,

### change `if(col==13)` to `if(col==13||col==14)`

However, in your function `updateMaster` you have the line `ds.getRange(i+1, 33).setValue(valuen);`, i.e. you are setting the value in column 33. Is this what you want to do for both column 13 and 14?

If not, modify your function to `function updateMaster(sn,valuen,col)` and differentiate between columns e.g. like

```
  if(col==13){
    ds.getRange(i+1, 33).setValue(valuen);   
   } else if(col==14){
    ds.getRange(i+1, 34).setValue(valuen);   
   }
```

and call  `updateMaster(sn,value,col);` within `function ReadRow(e)` .

> Full code:

```
 function updateMaster(sn,valuen,col) 
    {
      var destfile=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID");
      var ds=destfile.getSheetByName("SheetName");
      var lr=ds.getLastRow();
      var values=ds.getRange(1, 2,lr,1).getValues();
      for (var i=1;i<lr;i++)
      {
       // Browser.msgBox(values[i][0] + " " + sn)

        if(values[i][0]==sn){
          if(col==13){
            ds.getRange(i+1, 33).setValue(valuen);   
          } else if(col==14){
            ds.getRange(i+1, 34).setValue(valuen);   
          }
       }    
    }   

    function ReadRow(e) 
    {
      var range = e.range;
      sht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var col=range.getColumn();
      var row=range.getRow();
      var value=range.getValue();
      if(col==13||col==14){
        var sn=sht.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    //   Browser.msgBox(sn);
         updateMaster(sn,value,col);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The column 33 mentioned there is the destination sheet column where its being synced to. So column 13 has to sync with 33 and 14 has to sync with 34 column.

Comment: Ok, that's what the modified code snippets in my answer will do.

Comment: One last thing how can I define "Col" in another function? As I have another function at the bottom of this which I didnt include here. I am getting "ReferenceError: "col" is not defined. (line 50, file "Code")"

This is how it looks like

function updateAll()
{
  var file=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss=file.getSheetByName("ER");
  var lr=ss.getLastRow();
  var values=ss.getRange(1, 1,lr,13).getValues();
  for (var i=1;i<lr;i++)
  {
    var sn=values[i][1];
    var valuen=values[i][12];
    
    updateMaster(sn,valuen) ;
   
    
  }
}

https://pastebin.com/jaBKjEAj

Comment: from `var valuen=values[i][12];` I assume that you want to update column 13, so you can just define `var col=13` and call `updateMaster(sn,value,col);`

Comment: Alright I tried doing it however the updateALL function is only updating column 13 data into column 33 and not 14 and 34. Am i missing something? Here is the code which i am using for updateALL function https://pastebin.com/YzwVzpMi

Comment: Because it is not updating all values, but only `var valuen=values[i][12];`, that is column 13. If you want to update both columns, you have to modify the function. E.g. by modifying values to `var values=ss.getRange(1, 1,lr,13).getValues(); `, adding `var valuen2=values[i][13]; `, `var col2=14:` and making two calls - `updateMaster(sn,valuen,col);` and `updateMaster(sn,valuen,col2);`

Comment: Now its updating both the columns but its only updating data from column 13 and duplicating it to column 14 as well 
here is the  modified code; https://pastebin.com/UnQyCKVB

Comment: woops working now. I figured out the same variable issue

Comment: @mesa1001. I am glad it works. If my answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it.